# Extract Four-Character Matches from Strings

Tags: regex, string, bash, unix, awk

I need to extract the following four-character matches from the below string:

**Sites:**

```
KPAE
KPSC
KPUW
KRNT
KSEA
KSFF
KSHN
KTIW
```

**Data:**

```
{"sids": ["24222 1", "452670 2", "PAE 3", "KPAE 5", "USW00024222 6"], "name": "EVERETT SNOHOMISH AP"},
{"sids": ["24163 1", "PSC 3", "KPSC 5", "USW00024163 6"], "name": "PASCO TRI CITIES AP"},
{"sids": ["94129 1", "PUW 3", "KPUW 5", "USW00094129 6"], "name": "PULLMAN MOSCOW RGNL AP"},
{"sids": ["94248 1", "RNT 3", "KRNT 5", "USW00094248 6"], "name": "RENTON MUNI AP"},
{"sids": ["24233 1", "457473 2", "SEA 3", "72793 4", "KSEA 5", "USW00024233 6", "SEA 7"], "name": "SEATTLE TACOMA INTL AP"},
{"sids": ["94176 1", "SFF 3", "KSFF 5", "USW00094176 6"], "name": "SPOKANE FELTS FLD"},
{"sids": ["94227 1", "457585 2", "SHN 3", "KSHN 5", "USW00094227 6", "SHN 7"], "name": "SHELTON SANDERSON FLD"},
{"sids": ["94274 1", "TIW 3", "KTIW 5", "USW00094274 6"], "name": "TACOMA NARROWS AP"},
```

I have tried to extract these matches from the strings but, the position of them can change from string to string...

**Attempted Code:**

```
awk -F',' '{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -Po '"\K[A-Z]{4}\b' file

KPAE
KPSC
KPUW
KRNT
KSEA
KSFF
KSHN
KTIW
```

Comment: Hi. How can I go about also extracting all values that match `US*`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lack of information... I am looking to also extract all values that are similar to the following: `USW00024163`

Comment: You can then use: `grep -Po '\bUS\w*|"\K[A-Z]{4}\b' file`

Comment: Thank you! How can I get the results to print line-by-line in the following format? `KPAE,USW00024222`

Comment: Please don't extend the problem by comments. You can do: `grep -Po '\bUS\w*|"\K[A-Z]{4}\b' file | awk -v OFS=, 'NR%2{p=$1; next} {print p, $1}'`